# How can there be an infinite number of sequentially composite Fibonacci(p)?

Tags: number-theory

I ran into this counting function $a(n)\geq a(k)+1$ for the number of distinct prime factors of the $n$-th Fibonacci number, at OEIS.  Thank you Robert Israel!

Thank you for writing the proof there.
I had found the same thing years ago, but could never prove it beyond this:
Since $GCD(F_p, F_n) = FGCD(p,n) = F_1 = 1$, all factors must be characteristic.
I found that in way back Aug 1998.

Basically, All $F(nk)$ will have "at least" the same number of factors as $F(k)$, plus "at least" one new characteristic prime from Carmichael's theorem.
That is how I defined it without getting overly complicated, but with the same results.  I use the prime counting notation $\pi(n)$.

Now, my question:

Let $\pi(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $F(n)$.
So, if $k=1$, and $n$ is prime, then $1$ always divides $p$ and $\pi(p)\geq \pi(1)+1$.

If there really was an infinite number of consecutively composite $F(p)$ then wouldn't,
$\pi(p)\geq \pi(1)+2$ for all $F(p)$?  At least all subsequent $F(p)$?

Correct?

The way I see it, no new factors can be generated by $\pi(1)$, so zero factors are passed to $\pi(p).$  The only thing left generating factors is plus one from Carmichael's theorem.  The counter should show $\pi(p)\geq 2$ if there were an infinite number of consecutively composite $F(p)$.  Does the counter miss this, or what?

Comment: @Robert Israel, You are being paged.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If p and q are both primes, then all factors of F(pq) are characteristic, except for those of F(p) and F(q).

π(pq)>=π(q)+π(p)+1, except for {π(p^2)>=π(p)+1}

The number of distinct prime divisors of F(k) can now be replaced with the sum of the number of distinct prime divisors of each Fibonacci number with an index, of each distinct divisor, of k.

π(n)>=(π(k1)+π(k2)+...) +1

This appears to be more accurate.
Consider F247 π(19*13)>=π(13)+π(19)+1 or F(855) π(3*3*5*19)>=π(3)+π(5)+π(19)+1.

The number of distinct prime factors of the Fibonacci numbers with a prime index is directly relevant to the counting function.  Has anyone seen this before?  Reference?